# Add data to a table in the FROM Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add records of data to a table in the FROM statement, ideally without having to use TEMP tables.

The format of query would be something like:

```
SELECT
   [Employee].[ID]
  ,[Employee].[NAME]
FROM [EMPLOYEE]
UNION ALL
(45, 'Buck Rogers'),
(46, 'Twiki'),
(47, 'Col Wilma Deering')
```

Thank you for your help on this.

Historically I have added temporary record information to a TEMP table, and then interacted with this, but I figure there must be a way to load record information directly into the query.

Comment: I discovered how to add the values I needed to the record set, 

SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
    VALUES 
    (45, 'Buck Rogers')
    ,(46, 'Twiki')
    ,(47, 'Col Wilma Deering')
) AS T1(ID,Name)

But if there is a better way to do this I would be interested. Thank you!

Comment: Why should this be done in the FROM clause? I guess it would make more sense to show us both sample input and expected outcome and let the people here think about a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UNION ALL` statement in every pair of values and the `select` statement to pick them.

look the example here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/iNAYWPT1